# Change properties of graphic decoration ControlsFx

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I am new in using the ControlsFx library and what i am trying to do is to adjust some properties of the ERROR_IMAGE from GraphicValidationDecoration. For example, I want to use the same image for validations, but with another positioning(default is bottom left) and another size. Is that posssible?
I tried using StyleClassValidationDecoration, but i think that's just for the textfield itself, not the icon i am talking about.
I read that this was also requested by the community but i did not find the implementantion for it (https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/788/make-style-of-graphicvalidationdecoration)

Comment: that's a rather oldish link to controlsfx - they moved to https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx - see if the old issue is fixed (if not, you'll have to implement it yourself or get help by opening a new issue)

Comment: Yes, i saw that they moved to github, but i was just stating that this issue was already adressed in the past. @kleopatra, How can i see if the issue is fixed?